# Get Angular Environment in .js File

Tags: javascript, angular

i Have component to get list car from my Rest API like this:

```
export class CarIndexComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    apiUrl: string = environment.apiUrl + '/api/v1/cars-data';

    constructor( private _script: ScriptLoaderService ) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this._script.loadScripts( 'car-index', [
            'assets/app/js/pages/cars/data-ajax.js'
        ] );
    }
}
```

I call datatable ajax from script 'assets/app/js/pages/cars/data-ajax.js'

but inside the script i don't know how to call my apiUrl variable

```
method: 'GET',
url: apiUrl + '/api/v1/cars-data',
headers: {
  'authorization' : 'Bearer ' + user.token
}
```

the apiUrl show undefined.

Comment: Have you imported the environment.ts file in your CarIndexComponent?             
like this: import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

Comment: @kboul yes i already have

Comment: Why you do not import the apiUrl  in data-ajax.js file the same way as you did in the CarIndexComponent? Usually .js files are not placed inside assets folder where images or mock data are placed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have an external script that you need to use that way, but what you can do is add the api URL to a global variable, which your script can access

```
export class CarIndexComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
 //  apiUrl: string = environment.apiUrl + '/api/v1/cars-data';

    constructor( private _script: ScriptLoaderService ) 
    {
        window['apiUrl'] = environment.apiUrl + '/api/v1/cars-data';
    }
```

And in your script

```
method: 'GET',
url: window.apiUrl + '/api/v1/cars-data',
```

Comment: i have external script to call datatable ajax function, if i create a helper (.ts file) and call Datatable there, i got error  Property 'Datatable' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.

Comment: Glad to hear it. But I think it's be better if you could get Datatables to work properly.

Comment: yes, i'm new on Angluar, i will learn how to use Datatables properly. Thank you